# How to handle fetching image that doesn't exists yet in JavaScript when using LiipImagineBundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I would like to check if a file **exists** in NodeJS.

I saw this solution in another post :

```
const tryRequire = (path) => {
  try {
   return require(`${path}`);
  } catch (err) {
   return null;
  }
};
```

But is it really a good solution?

In my case I'm checking **a lot of file**, so I'm gonna import with the require each file I'll check (so a lot of files). I just want to know if the file exists or not and don't import it.

How could I do this?

---

**EDIT:**

I'm explaining my issue in details.

I'm in a Symfony and React project. **I'm new with React.**

There is a possibility to upload images in a chat. When uploading an image, I call a Symfony route. In this route I use Liip Imagine bundle. So I'm doing something like this to cache the image :

```
public function new(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
{
    $rewardImagePath = $this->uploaderHelper->asset($media, 'imageFile');
        if($rewardImagePath) {
            $cacheImagePath = $this->cacheManager->getBrowserPath($rewardImagePath, 'live_feed_message');
        }
}
```

The issue is that function getBrowserPath give me the URL of the future cached file. But the file takes a significant time (like 5/10 seconds sometimes) to be created. So in my front I have the new chat message but in reality the file associated don't exists on the server. So it displays a message without image.

For some unknow reasons, if I'm doing a while file exists in this controller, I got a time out and the file is never created. That's why I'm trying to check the file existence in react side.

Comment: use other nodejs techniques ... like `fs.existsSync(path)` method

Comment: Are you in a browser or node environment?

Comment: Is this a React question or a Node question?

Comment: surely this can't be in the browser ...

Comment: JavaScript runs in browser unless you use node.js, which runs most servers and OSes. Therefore JavaScript can't access file system(node.js can).

Comment: Sorry I'm using React environment. Don't mentionned in post but I added tag..

Comment: so, your browser code is trying to see if files exist on the server? Wouldn't the server side be the place to determine their existence?

Comment: I edited the question since you mentioned that `require` works, it indicates that it's unrelated to the browser or React.

Comment: Bad choice of duplicate @EmileBergeron if you read the OP's comments

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't matter if he uses React, it's developed in a Node environment anyway,

Comment: yeah ... but the *browser* can't use server side *modules* like `fs` for example - i.e the accepted answer in your "duplicate" suggests `You can use fs.existsSync()` ... that won't work

Comment: @JaromandaX my guess is that it's an XY problem where OP doesn't really need to check if a file exists, but only him can clarify that.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - I apologise ... OP has clarified, you are indeed correct (as was I in the very first comment)

Comment: @JaromandaX React is developed in a Node environment, where server side modules are available. Checking file existence only makes sense at build time anyway.

Comment: well ... the question now asks "I would like to check if a file exists in NodeJS" - so `react` is a moot point :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I could be wrong as well, OP should clarify.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - "check if a file exists in NodeJS" is clear I would think

Comment: I updated my post to explain correctly and with more details my issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Looks like we were wrong. While unrelated to React, it is also unrelated to Node.

Comment: My guess would be that you should do the check in Php and return a temporary image file URL (like a generic placeholder) while the image is not available. Then, when fetching other messages, you can check again and update the payload accordingly.

Comment: Otherwise: [JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92720/1218980)

Comment: I tried your link but it doesn't works. I think that's because when we call the URL, LiipImagine Bundle recreate the image in cache if it doesn't exists. So it probably return each time a success and never an error. But it takes sometimes a long time to generate the image and during this time I've no images

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
xhr.send();

if (xhr.status == "404") {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: This assumes they are looking to do something client-side and not in NodeJS, which still isn't completely clear.

Comment: Yes i saw his reply after, i'll leave it here even if its a repost, might help someone